# iPhone 4 stuck in recovery mode after restore

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

When I went to restore an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.2 with iTunes, I got it stuck in recovery mode.

I believe the device has been restored, since it has been reverted from 'Mike's iPhone' to just 'iPhone'. But now I'm stuck in recovery mode.

I used the Reiboot tool on my Windows 7 laptop, but that didn't work, so it prompted me to download the firmware, since the software was damaged. I did, but I have to pay to begin the process with Reiboot. Is there any **free** way to fix this?

Note: I've also tried to use the 'Tiny Umbrella' tool on my laptop, and that won't even start. I do have an old computer tower running Windows XP, maybe I could use Tiny Umbrella on that?

Comment: "I have to pay to begin the process" ?? Pay who? There is no charge for any iOS. The free way is iTunes.

Comment: You clearly have only skimmed my question, Tetsujin. I have already attempted to restore the device with iTunes, but the iPhone is now stuck in recovery mode, and the process will not complete.

Comment: I picked out the point that made no sense & may cost you money. But if you want to pay for something unnecessarily, who am I to stop you?

Comment: Tetsujin raises a fair point, even after thoroughly reading your question I do not understand why you suggest you must pay. Is it Reiboot asking for payment?

Comment: Indeed, it is Reiboot that asked for payment. I apologize, did I not specify?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've edited the question with that. I'm unfamiliar with Reiboot personally and there are plenty of tools which download the IPSWs freely available from Apple's site, expecting you to use iTunes to do the restore (also free as expected). I've always used iTunes to restore — I wouldn't trust a separate tool like that. Exiting recovery mode into a normal boot is also something you shouldn't generally need a tool for, since you can force a hardware reboot using the buttons on the device, even if you don't want to enter DFU in the case of an actual recovery *loop*.

Comment: That's what I'm in, a recovery loop.

Answer (score 1):

Enter DFU and perform a DFU restore.

1. Connect the device to iTunes using USB.
2. Hold the Power and Home buttons until the display turns black.
3. Immediately release the power button but keep holding Home until iTunes displays a message that the device must be restored. The screen of the iPhone will remain black.
4. Use iTunes to restore the device.

Comment: This method only looped me back into recovery mode.

Comment: I apologize, I re-read your answer. The process has begun, and I will notify you if it works.

Comment: This did nothing for me, sorry. It reached the point of 'Verifying restore' and then it stopped.

Comment: @YSP It's only been ¾h, I would have expected it to take at least an hour. Did it say anything when it stopped?

Comment: No, just 'iPhone could not be restored'.